# Aвтоматическая авторизация в steam + "запомнить мой пароль " Bat файлом

Tags: steam, bat

Я написал Bat файл с помощью которого автоматически захожу в мои аккунт Steam.

```
`@echo off
taskkill /f /im steam.exe
@echo off
Start Start C:\"Program Files (x86)"\Steam\steam.exe -login %login %password 
exit`
```

Просто проблема в том что мне нужно поставить галочку "запомнить мой пороль"(можете видеть в изображении) no но это у меня не получается .
Как я могу это сделать помогите пожалуста.

[image: Steam]

Comment: Скорее всего тебе нужен `Autoit`.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы поставить эту галочку, нужно найти адрес памяти в 1 байт. 0 - выкл 1 - вкл. Бат файл не умеет перезаписывать память. Тебе нужен C++.